# How do I print rows from my table in the MYSQL server when I run the php file

Tags: php, mysql

How do I print rows from my table in the MYSQL server when I run the php file? I have used the prepare statement to prepare a query. I am not sure how to output the result of that query.  My code is as follows:

```
// Check connection 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

putenv("ODBCINI=/etc/dwwdwd.ini");
putenv("NZ_ODBC_INI_PATH=/etc/");
putenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/export/home/joadf/netezza/lib64");
echo "Whats up";


$lvar = $coni->prepare(
    'SELECT * FROM TABLE A limit 10');
$lvar->execute();
$lvar->fetch();
?>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) or rather where is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to use `bind_result()` [Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php). There are examples on that page. Basically you use bind result to set the variables where the data from the query is stored and then read them that way. You should put the fetch part inside a `while` loop so you can iterate over the results

You will have n number of varaible within the `bind_result()` statement depending on how many cols you want from the db.

Example if requesting 3 cols from db
`$lvar->bind_result($a, $b, $c);`

Now $a, $b, $c contain the data of the first row in the order that the cols are listed after calling `$lvar->fetch()`.

Each time you call `$lvar->fetch()` the variables are updated until there are no more rows at which case the fetch statement returns `false`

This code should do the trick

```
$lvar = $coni->prepare(
'SELECT * FROM TABLE A limit 10');
$lvar->execute();
$lvar->bind_result($a, $b, $c);
while($lvar->fetch()) {
    echo $a . $b . $c;
}
```

Comment: When I run your code, I only see "What's up". I do not see the 10 rows in my table A.

Comment: Will you put a echo inside the while loop to see if that is iterating?

Comment: Yes it iterates as it prints out "blah" a certain number of times

Comment: So thats working, try instead of the eaco changing it to `var_dump($a)` do you see anything now?

Comment: "instead of each"? Do I have to replace the echo statement with var_dump?

Comment: I see NULL NULL NULL..NULL. MY code was while($lvar->fetch()) {
   var_dump($a);
}

Comment: I got it. It seems this code does not work.

Comment: So you did get it? Good im glad sorry I went out for the night